# How can I read as string and then make it int vector;

Tags: c++, vector

Lets say I have txt.file as

```
7 8 9
10 11 1
14 15 1
```

I want to keep the line and then put them in a nested vector. I have done this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<vector<int> > data;
    vector<int> temp;

    string file;

    cout << "Enter a file: ";
    cin >> file;

    ifstream infile(file);

    if (!infile.good()) {

        cout << "Enter a  valid file: " << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string read;
    while (!infile.eof()) {

        getline(infile, read);
        istringstream iss(read);

        copy(istream_iterator<int>(iss), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(temp));

        data.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << data[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Now the output I get is  like this:

```
7 8 9 
7 8 9 10 11 1 
7 8 9 10 11 1 14 15 1
```

I am not sure why previous content is repeating. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should declare temp inside the while-loop body.
With C++11 or later you can simply do: 
`data.emplace_back(istream_iterator<int>{iss}, istream_iterator<int>{});`

Comment: Compile with a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among the multitude of things wrong.

1. You use `std::cin` and `std::cout`, but never `#include <iostream>`
2. You use `std::vector`, but never `#include <vector>`
3. You use `std::string`, but never `#include <string>`
4. You append your populated line vector, but never reset the vector.

Note that you don't have to do (4) if you simply ensure the vector being appended *from* is, in fact, in local scope and as such expires before the next line. Better still, just use a temporary (which I'll demonstrate next).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;

    std::cout << "Enter a file: ";
    std::cout.flush();

    std::string filename;
    if (std::cin >> filename)
    {
        std::ifstream file(filename);
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            std::string line;
            while (std::getline(file, line))
            {
                std::istringstream iss(line);
                data.emplace_back(
                    std::istream_iterator<int>{iss},
                    std::istream_iterator<int>{});
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto const &v : data)
    {
        for (auto x : v)
            std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
}
```

A notable problem fixed here is the avoidance of using `std::istream::eof` in a loop conditional. It is rarely correct, and in your case, it was wrong. See this question and answers for why: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons?)

Answer (score 0):

`back_inserter(temp)` is adding your next lines to `temp` but you don't reset the variable so every line is appended to the end.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Would you mind to share how can I reset  variable so that line is not appended to the end. Thank you so much again.